# xssAPI cannot be resolved error in my CQ5 component jsp

Tags: xss, aem

Below is the code snippet:

```
<%@taglib prefix="cq" uri="http://www.day.com/taglibs/cq/1.0" %>
<%@taglib prefix="sling" uri="http://sling.apache.org/taglibs/sling/1.0" %>
<sling:defineObjects />
<cq:defineObjects />
 <label class="form_label" for="send_to"><%=xssAPI.encodeForHTML(sendToLabel)%></label>
```

Even I included global.jsp also still getting compilation error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of CQ5 are you using? If it is CQ 5.4, `xssAPI` is not available in it when you include global.jsp.

Instead you could use the [XSSProtectionService.class](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-4/javadoc/com/day/cq/xss/XSSProtectionService.html) to protect from XSS.

The XSSProtectionService can be obtained from `sling.getService()` and the `protectFromXSS()` can be used.

```
final XSSProtectionService xss = sling.getService(XSSProtectionService.class);
xss.protectFromXSS(sendToLabel);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is caused by the unknown variable `sendToLabel`. Use the `properties` [ValueMap](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling5/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ValueMap.html) to get this property:

```
<%=xssAPI.encodeForHTML(properties.get("sendToLabel", String.class))%>
```

Comment: No Tomek, sendToLabel is already declared String sendToLabel=propertiesfile.getProperty("sendToLabel");. I didn't include the whole code in my description.We are retrieving this value from a properties file

Comment: Could you post the whole code or make a simpler version of your component that suffers from the same problem? And include the compilation error body?